# Changing the order of barchart in stacked bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

Can anyone help me to change the order of bar graph . Here legend is showing in correct format but dont know why chart is changed

[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYe0w.png)

[my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxoW8.png)

```
ggplot(x,aes(x=Total,y=Type,fill=status))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity',width=0.2)+
  theme_classic()+
  #geom_text(aes(label = stat(x),group = Type),stat = "summary",fun = sum,vjust = .20,hjust= 1)+
  theme(axis.line.y = element_blank(),axis.ticks = element_blank(),legend.position = "bottom",
        axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold", color = "black", size = 10, angle = 45, hjust = 1))+
  labs(x="", y="", fill="")+

 scale_fill_manual(values=c("#284a8d", "#00B5CE"))
```

Comment: Please attach some sample data for us to reproduce the problem with, for example copying the output of `dput(x)`.

Comment: And also tell me how to add the totals for each bar refer the image for more details @teunbrand

Comment: is any other way to solve this problem like using ggplotly or else any other idea @teunbrand

Answer (score 0):

This is about as close as I could get it:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(x,aes(x=Total,y=Type,fill=factor(status, c("Open", "Closed"))))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity',width=0.2)+
  geom_text(aes(label = after_stat(x)),
            stat = "summary",fun.data = function(x){data.frame(y = sum(x))}, 
            hjust= 0, position = position_stack(0))+
  geom_text(aes(label = after_stat(x), group = Type),
            stat = "summary",fun.data = function(x){data.frame(y = sum(x))}, 
            hjust= 0, position = position_stack(1))+
  labs(x="", y="", fill="")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#284a8d", "#00B5CE"), 
                    limits = c("Closed", "Open")) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold", color = "black", 
                                   size = 10, angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: exactly this is what i want but can you remove the extra numbers 17,29,113@tenubrand refer the image for clarification

Comment: Yeah just comment out or remove the second `geom_text()`.

Comment: look at the EIC accepted in image for reference @tenubrand

Comment: colour=ifelse(x$status == "Closed","#FFFFFF","#000000") as per the image i need to show the closed in white color but while using the code inside geom_text i m facing an error let me know this one